# How to pass dynamc comparison code to Array.sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2D array that I want to sort using dynamically selected columns. Here is my working example.

```
table.sort((a,b)=> (a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) || a[0].localeCompare(b[0])));
```

but I can't figure out the dynamic column selection part. I thought 'just create a string and pass that to sort' but that generates an error. Here's where I am now...

```
function dynamicSort(table, columns){
  //This explicit code works great
  //    table.sort((a,b)=> (a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) || a[0].localeCompare(b[0])));
  //and I'm trying to make the columns dynamic by doing something like this 

  //create this string 
  //   '(a,b)=> (a[1].localeCompare(b[1]) || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))' 
  //with dynamic values for the column numbers
  let sortString = `(a,b)=> (` +
                    `a[${columns[0]}].localeCompare(b[${columns[0]}])` +
                    ` || ` +
                    `a[${columns[1]}].localeCompare(b[${columns[1]}])` +
                    `)`;

  //and then pass it to sort which returns the following error
  //TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined
  table.sort(sortString);
  
}

function testIt(){
  var table = [['John','Doe'], ['Adam','Doe'], ['Sam','Adams'],['Bud','Wiser']];
  var sortColumns=[1,0];

  dynamicSort(table,sortColumns);
  for (row in table) console.log(table[row].join(", "));
}
```

I've also tried creating a `new function` using `sortString` but couldn't get that to work either.
I think I'm on the right track but just don't have the right syntax.

If it matters, I'm using Google Apps Script platform for this.

Would greatly appreciate some help here. I've been programming other languages for years but really new to JS. Feeling like a bit of a baby...

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. If `var table = [['John','Doe'], ['Adam','Doe'], ['Sam','Adams'],['Bud','Wiser']];` is your sample input value, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output value you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use use a string of code at all. You can directly use bracket notation to access a dynamic index.

Here is a more general version that works for any number of columns to sort by:

```js
function dynamicSort(table, columns){
  table.sort((a, b) => columns.reduce((acc, curr) => 
    acc || a[curr].localeCompare(b[curr]), 0));
}

function testIt(){
  var table = [['John','Doe'], ['Adam','Doe'], ['Sam','Adams'],['Bud','Wiser']];
  var sortColumns = [1,0];
  dynamicSort(table, sortColumns);
  for (const row of table) console.log(row.join(", "));
}
testIt();
```